# Сортировка данных при выборке при помощи SQL запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, алгоритм

Таблица в базе

```
| ID | Time         |
|----|--------------|
| 1  |              |// пустое значение
| 2  | 20:00        |
| 3  | 19:00        |
| 4  | 13:00        |
| 5  |              |// пустое значен
```

Структура таблицы показана на схеме выше. 
Делаю выборку из базы с сортировкой "...ORDER BY Time" и получаю такую выборку:

```
| 1  |              |
| 5  |              |
| 4  | 13:00        |
| 3  | 19:00        |
| 2  | 20:00        |
```

Все логично, но хотелось бы получить выборку чтобы сначала выводились строки со значениями (в порядке их возрастания) , а уже после них пустые. То есть вот так:

```
| 4  | 13:00        |
| 3  | 19:00        |
| 2  | 20:00        |
| 1  |              |
| 5  |              |
```

Возможно ли это реализовать такую сортировку на уроне SQL-запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте что нибудь типа:

```
order by coalesce(time,'99:99')
```

Это если "пустое значение" - это NULL. И 99:99 замените на какое нибудь 23:59:59, если там действительно поле типа time

Comment: Нет, столбец имеет тип Varchar. 
И база данных SQLite...

Comment: А зачем тогда ставите что это mysql

Comment: @Алексей Посмотрел, в sqlite так же есть coalesce, так что должно работать, и раз varchar - то 99:99 как раз то что надо

Comment: @Алексей Даже проверил сейчас, на sqlite3 данная сортировка работает как и заказано

Comment: Отлично! То что нужно. Большое спасибо!